# python subprocess communicate() block

Tags: python, subprocess, blocking

I am using the *subprocess* module to call an external program (plink.exe) to log-in to a server; but when I call communicate to read the output, it is blocking. The code is below:

```
 import subprocess
 process = subprocess.Popen('plink.exe hello@10.120.139.170 -pw 123456'.split(), shell=False, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
 print process.communicate() #block here
```

I know the block is because `plink.exe` it still running; but I need to read the output  before the subprocess terminates. Is there anyway to do that?

Comment: Do you need to interact with plink, or you just need to make the call and read the std output without blocking?

Comment: related: [Python: read streaming input from subprocess.communicate()](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2715847/4279)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The whole purpose of the `communicate` method is to wait for the process to finish and return all the output. If you don't want to wait, don't call `communicate`. Instead, read from the `stdout` or `stderr` attribute to read the output.

If the process outputs to both `stdout` and `stderr` (and you want to read it separately), you will have to be careful to actually read from both without blocking, or you can deadlock. This is fairly hard on Windows, and you may wish to use the [`pexpect`](http://pexpect.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) module instead.

Comment: `pexpect` doesn't work on Windows. [`asyncio`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20697159/4279) or [threads](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4896288/4279) could be used to read both streams without blocking.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because "plink.exe" needs to take in input arguments, if you don't pass them, it will block until data are given, you could try adding arguments in method `communicate(input)`

Answer (score -1):

I faced a similar situation where I had to execute a single command `lmstat -a` and then get the output of the terminal.

If you just need to run a single command and then read the output, you can use the following code:

```
import subprocess

Username = 'your_username'
Password = 'your_password'
IP = 'IP_of_system'
Connection_type = '-ssh' #can have values -ssh -telnet -rlogin -raw -serial

p = subprocess.Popen(['plink', Connection_type, '-l', Username, '-pw', Password, IP], \
                     shell = False, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = p.communicate('lmstat -a\nexit\n'.encode())
print(out.decode())
```

Comment: As @Thomas said, this is a blocking and not a non-blocking approach