# python subprocess.Popen freezes tkinter window

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, subprocess

Firstly, I create an Tkinter window that contains a button and that button triggers the function that creates new subprocess but after creating new subprocess my first window doesn't respond. I am using python 3.7

(It happens even if I launch new subprocess that contains just a window and nothing else)

**Here is my code**

```
from tkinter import *
import pickle
import sys
import subprocess


def bom(exitX, exitY, startY, startX, entries1):

    theproc = subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, "Learner.py"], stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
    theproc.communicate()


masterq = Tk()

##..some gui code..##

Button(masterq, text='SAVE GRID - START AND END POINTS',
       command=lambda: bom(e1.get(), e2.get(), e3.get(), e4.get(), entries)).grid(
    row=4,
    column=0,
    sticky=W,
    pady=4)

masterq.mainloop()
```

Comment: the code is python 3 since t in tkinter is small

Comment: @SmartManoj Oh, mistyped I edited thanks.

Comment: I guess it is because `communicate()` blocks the thread. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2133345/python-subprocess-communicate-block

Comment: @Poolka I thought communicate prevents blocking ! I delete the line and it worked ! thanks !